# Can python open an application on a mac and execute an action?

Tags: python, macos

I would like to have my code open facetime and call someone
I currently can open the program using
 import subprocess
                subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/Facetime.app"]) but i would like to take it a step further and automate the call.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: You probably want to do this:

```
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/Facetime.app",
                 "tel://{}".format(number)])
```

Or, if you want it to make an audio-only call, add `&audio=yes` to the end.

---

Only a few apps have a command-line tool to control them. Many macOS apps have a powerful scripting interface meant to be used by Automator and/or AppleScript but easily usable from Python—but FaceTime does not. And even trying to use UI event scripting (where you simulate mouse clicks and the like) is painful with FaceTime.

But FaceTime *does* know how to handle the `tel` URL scheme. So, if you hand it `tel://8675309` from the `open` command (or the `SystemEvents` scripting interface, or Automator, or Safari, etc.), it will dial 8675309.

Well, actually, by default, it won't dial the number, it'll pop up a dialog asking whether you want to dial the number—same as when you click a phone number in an email or note. As far as I know, you can't change that from the calling side, only by setting a global preference to always dial without popping up that dialog. And I think the preference to change that has been hidden since 10.8 or so. (I'd bet somewhere on Ask Different there's a question with the current information on how to change it, but I don't know what it is.)

---

By the way, if you just `open tel://8675309` without specifying an app, that will open whatever app is your default `tel` handler, which is usually FaceTime—but sometimes Skype, or older versions of Google Voice, or various other third-party programs will take that over. So if you want your script to switch to Skype if you change your default, leave off the `-a` bit; if you want to use FaceTime no matter what, leave it on.

Comment: Where shall you add `&audio=yes`to the end of the code to only make phone calls?